# Auditing Customization in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to add Audit on the customizations done by Team on Server, on Entity Forms in my CRM solution.

I know there is a feature in CRM 2011 for Auditing Entity and Field changes in CRM 2011, but I want to ensure that if somebody changes the form without editing entity and fields ex: shifting controls from left to right, it should be logged somewhere, is there any solution to such requirement in CRM 2011.

I am a beginner to CRM 2011, so if my question doesn't make sense, please excuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything that audits customization changes (at least out of the box).  Here is a list of the auditing capabilities that dynamics has out of the box [Auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309664.aspx).

If you need to do this, you can see if there is a 3rd party tool available in the market place, but you can do this yourself if you want to put the development work into it.  I would register an plugin on the `Publish` and `PublishAll` messages and then store the changes in a custom entity called Customization Audit (or something to that degree).  You can then display whatever granularity you wish to display in the audit.

Answer (score 1):

There is not OOB functionality to log the customization changes.

Also if in theory it is possible to log some changes at a certain level (using a plugin triggered on the publish messages for example), the implementation will require a moderate amount of time with not so sure good results.

I suggest (this is my personal opinion) to teach the developers that will customize the system to track by themselves the changes they made (for example using a shared excel file)

Answer (score 0):

The idea sounds solid but in my experience programmers use that button tens if not hundreds of time a day.  You’ll probably end up with more zip files than you can chew.

If you’re still interested this is what you should do …

1. Create unmanaged solutions for each entity that u wish to audit.
2. Attach an asynchronously plug-in to the publish message (as stated above).
3. Export the solution of the entity being modified using ExportSolutionRequest
4. Save the file to disk using a well defined naming convention.
5. Use a comparison tool such as beyond compare to browse the xml differences.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I came across this yesterday and thought I would add something in case someone else sees this question later. While there is no way in the stock CRM database to audit publishing customizations, if you are scraping your IIS logs into a database with MS LogParser or similar or even just saving them off to a file archive, you can search for the string "SystemCustomization.asmx", and presuming you have logging turned up to show the userid (the "User Name (cs-username)" field is checked in the IIS logging settings), you can find when publications were done and by whom. It doesn't tell you WHAT was published (e.g., whether it was a "Publish All" or not), but it does tell you when (UTC time by default) and who.

Answer (score 0):

We use this auditing in our projects - https://xrmciframework.codeplex.com/
Of course it requires to do run couple of scripts to log changes but it worth spent time.